# Convert from type `T a` to `T b` without boilerplate

Tags: haskell, ghc, scrap-your-boilerplate, ghc-generics

So, I have an AST data type with a large number of cases, which is parameterized by an "annotation" type

```
data Expr a = Plus a Int Int
    | ...
    | Times a Int Int
```

I have annotation types `S` and `T`, and some function `f :: S -> T`. I want to take an `Expr S` and convert it to an `Expr T` using my conversion `f` on each `S` which occurs within an Expr value.

Is there a way to do this using SYB or generics and avoid having to pattern match on every case? It seems like the type of thing that this is suited for. I just am not familiar enough with SYB to know the specific way to do it.

Comment: sounds like a lot like a `Functor`.  The `fmap` function has the type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`.  If you say that `Expr` is a `Functor`, then `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Expr a -> Expr b)`.

Comment: If you want to avoid the boilerplate of the writing `Functor` definition too, you can use the `DeriveFunctor` extension.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `Functor` instance. This can be automatically derived by GHC using the `DeriveFunctor` extension.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your follow-up question, it seems that a generics library is more appropriate to your situation than Functor.  I'd recommend just using the function given on SYB's [wiki page](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scrap_your_boilerplate):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable, ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Data.Generics
import Unsafe.Coerce

newtype C a = C a deriving (Data,Typeable)

fmapData :: forall t a b. (Typeable a, Data (t (C a)), Data (t a)) =>
    (a -> b) -> t a -> t b
fmapData f input = uc . everywhere (mkT $ \(x::C a) -> uc (f (uc x)))
                    $ (uc input :: t (C a))
    where uc = unsafeCoerce
```

The reason for the extra `C` type is to avoid a problematic corner case where there are occurrences of fields at the same type as `a` (more details on the wiki).  The caller of `fmapData` doesn't need to ever see it.

This function does have a few extra requirements compared to the real `fmap`: there must be instances of `Typeable` for `a`, and `Data` for `t a`.  In your case `t a` is `Expr a`, which means that you'll need to add a `deriving Data` to the definition of `Expr`, as well as have a `Data` instance in scope for whatever `a` you're using.