# Deriving functor instance, not on last type argument

Tags: haskell, ghc, scrap-your-boilerplate, ghc-generics

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674052/convert-from-type-t-a-to-t-b-without-boilerplate) I asked earlier today.

I have an AST data type with a large number of cases, which is parameterized by an "annotation" type

```
data Expr ann def var = Plus a Int Int
    | ...
    | Times a Int Int
    deriving (Data, Typeable, Functor)
```

I've got concrete instances for def and var, say `Def` and `Var`.

What I want is to automatically derive `fmap` which operates as a functor on the first argument. I want to derive a function that looks like this:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Expr a Def Var) -> (Expr b Def Var)
```

When I use normal `fmap`, I get a compiler message that indicates fmap is trying to apply its function to the last type argument, not the first.

Is there a way I can derive the function as described, without writing a bunch of boilerplate? I tried doing this:

```
newtype Expr' a = E (Expr a Def Var)
    deriving (Data, Typeable, Functor)
```

But I get the following error:

```
  Constructor `E' must use the type variable only as the last argument of a data type
```

I'm working with someone else's code base, so it would be ideal if I don't have to switch the order of the type arguments everywhere.

Comment: You can do an ugly hack where you define a different, identical type with the type arguments in the correct order, derive the Functor instance for that, then use `unsafeCoerce` on that. This is really quite bad and I don't recommend it. The simplest option is to roll your own deriving functionality; or simply refactor existing code. If you don't mind pulling in a big dependency, take a look at the [derive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/derive-2.5.5/docs/Data-Derive-Functor.html) package.

Comment: `Expr ann def` can't have a `Functor` instance unless `var` is the type variable that changes with `fmap`.

Comment: It's a shame there's no `DeriveFunctor`-type functionality for the `hask` package. The `hask` package provides, among other things, a polykinded `Functor` type class which is able to `fmap` over type variables deeper than the first one (as long as all the type variables to the right of it have `Functor` instances as well and it sounds like this would be trivially true in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, this isn't possible, because `Functor` requires that the changing type variable be in the last position.  Only type constructors of kind `* -> *` can have `Functor` instances, and your `Expr` doesn't have that kind.

Do you really need a `Functor` instance?  If you just want to avoid the boilerplate of writing an fmap-like function, something like SYB is a better solution (but really the boilerplate isn't that bad, and you'd only write it once).

If you need `Functor` for some other reason (perhaps you want to use this data structure in some function with a `Functor` constraint), you'll have to choose whether you want the instance or the type variables in the current order.

Answer (score 2):

You can exploit a type synonym for minimizing the changes to the original code:

```
data Expr' def var ann = Plus a Int Int   -- change this to Expr', correct order
    | ...
    | Something (Expr ann def var)        -- leave this as it is, with the original order
    deriving (Data, Typeable, Functor)

type Expr ann def var = Expr' def var ann
```

The rest of the code can continue using `Expr`, unchanged. The only exceptions are class instances such as `Functor`, which as you noticed require a certain order in the parameters. Hopefully `Functor` is the only such class you need.

The auto-derived `fmap` function has type

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Expr' def var a -> Expr' def var b
```

which can be written as

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Expr a def var -> Expr b def var
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't as helpful as it appears.  Type synonyms can't be partially applied, so you'd never be able to use `Expr ann def` anywhere (except possibly with the `LiberalTypeSynonyms` extension, but there are still limits).  One could use a newtype, but that still doesn't solve the OP's primary issue, which is wanting to get an fmap-like function without having to write it manually.